# Where is module prefork.c settings on AWS EC2 LAMP stack?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I am trying to edit the apache prefork.c configuration on my AWS EC2 micro instance (LAMP).

The module prefork.c settings:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>

StartServers 3

MinSpareServers 2

MaxSpareServers 5

ServerLimit 10

MaxClients 10

MaxRequestsPerChild 100
```

are usually in `httpd.conf` but they are not in that file on my system.

If I run `apachectl -V` from the command line I get the following output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)
Server built:   Jul 29 2016 21:42:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
threaded:     no
forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Does anyone know where they are or if I need to create a file myself so that I can edit them?